# "Of"—meaning in "The fox ate of it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> A fox once invited a stork to dine with him. He set before her a shallow dish of food. The fox ate **of** it greedily.

I think "*up*" should be used instead of "*of*".

Comment: This usage is very old-fashioned and archaic. Is this one of Aesop's fables? Which edition?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Everyday English —by Jean Sherwood Rankin

Comment: First published 1903.

Comment: Maybe related: in Dutch both "of" and "from" translate to the same word ("van"). I believe in English "of" and "from" also used to mean the same too, or at least they are closely related. Substituting "of" with "from" in your sentence makes a lot more sense. Like "the fox ate from the dish".

Comment: @Ivo Except that I'd interpret "it" to be referring to the food, not the dish, in this context - in which case, "from" would sound a little strange. But in any case, as mentioned above, this is quite old-fashioned English.

Comment: You should put an ellipsis between the 2nd and 3rd sentences of the example.  A lot goes on between those events. @MichaelHarvey [The Fox and the Stork](https://fablesofaesop.com/the-fox-and-the-stork.html), much abridged - and apparently serialised.

Comment: Everyday English? With sentence structure like this, it's more like Yesteryear English.

Comment: would make more sense if the stork was the one eating.

Comment: if you were going to use 'up' in this context, i'd suggest: 'the fox ate it up greedily'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original is fine.

Substituting "up" would give

> Ate up it greedily

which is just wrong. You could put

> Ate it up greedily

but that has a different meaning. Your original means he ate (some or all) of it. Using "up" means he ate it all.

You could just drop "of":

> Ate it greedily

if you like.

Comment: Note that "ate of it" carries the implication that he did not eat *all* of it. I would not expect to see the word of used here if he had eaten all of it.

Answer (score 10):

The sentence is correct. M-W gives [the following definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of) of the preposition "of":

> used as a function word to indicate a whole or quantity from which a part is removed or expended
> | gave *of* his time

A more common expression is "partake of (something)", but "eat of (something)" is sometimes used, too. As noted in a comment, it is somewhat old-fashioned. Here is [an example](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%201:31-33&version=KJV) from the King James version of the Bible:

> Therefore shall they eat of the fruit of their own way, and be filled with their own devices. (Proverbs 1:31)

Comment: I think in this context "of" could simply be replaced with "from" or not? Like "The fox ate from it". "it" referring to the dish. Just like "he ate from the plate" or "He drank from the cup". Would you agree?

Comment: @Ivo No, _from_ wouldn’t work here. _Of_ is used with the food/drink that’s being consumed; _from_ implies a container that holds that food/drink. There isn’t really another way to phrase exactly what the original version says, except perhaps by using a completely different expression, like “the fox greedily _tucked into it_”. That would be roughly equivalent, but still not quite the same (tucking in implies _beginning_ to eat the food, whereas eating of it doesn’t emphasise beginning, middle or end).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet but "dish" is a container. They even mention it's a shallow dish. So dish in this context is the container, not the food itself

Comment: @Ivo Ah yes, I’d missed that. It’s not obvious just from the syntax, but when _of_ is used, ‘it’ in the following sentence can only logically refer to the food, not to the dish. If it had been the dish (“the fox ate of the dish greedily”), that would mean the fox started eating the actual porcelain, which would probably not be healthy, even for a fox. If it had said “the fox ate from it greedily”, however, ‘it’ would indeed refer to the dish and end up meaning much the same thing (since eating [food] from the dish ≈ eating [some] of the food).

Answer (score 3):

No, *of* is correct. It means that the fox ate some of it, but maybe didn't completely finish it.

The only way *up* would fit is like this, with a different word order:
*The fox ate it up.*
That would mean that the fox ate all of it.

(The fox may be saving room in his stomach for a meal of the stork herself!)

Comment: What is the meaning of"of" here as a Preposition??

Comment: It's as I explained- *ate of it* means the same as *ate some of it*. He ate some but maybe didn't finish it all.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't mentioned that this use is archaic. Nobody would write "ate of it" today unless they were being deliberately archaic.

Comment: @ColinFine True, but *partake of* has the same sense, and the same use of the preposition *of*, which is the focus of the OP, I think. Also, the other example, *gave of his time* sounds odd, but not with an adverb - *gave generously of his time*.

Comment: @Sam it means "participate in the event of eating it"

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers mention that in modern English, we would add "*some*" to the sentence to keep the meaning the same.

As already stated

> The fox ate of it greedily.

implies that the fox ate some of the food on the plate, *but not all*.

Therefore, it would make sense to say, in modern English:

> The fox ate *some* of it greedily.

Although, in this case, it doesn't make much sense, because, given that the adverb *greedily* is included, one would expect that the whole plate's worth of food to be consumed.

However, for other examples of "*of*" given in the [other answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/337514/15311), inserting "*some*" makes more sense. So, instead of:

> He gave of his time.

use

> He gave *some* of his time.

Comment: A closer equivalent in current English would be something along the lines of “The fox started eating greedily” or “The fox greedily tucked in”, substituting the atelic aspect of _ate of it_ with an inchoative aspect that’s more readily available.